# Help needed on convex optimization!!

Tags: convex-optimization

[image: !]

Can some please help me in solving the below questions. I want to prove the below functions are convex, concave or neither.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: 1) Notice that $(1-t)x_{1}+tx_{2}-y=(1-t)(x_{1}-y)+t(x_{2}-y)$ and that norms are convex.

2) $x_{1}^{2}+3x_{2}^{4}-2x_{1}-6x_{2}=(x_{1}-1)^{2}-1+(3x_{2}^{4}-6x_{2})$ is a convex function and $\max\{f(x),0\}=\frac{f(x)+\lvert f(x)\rvert}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful facts:

Any norm is convex. If $f$ is convex and $T$ is affine then $g(x) = f(T(x))$ is convex. A conic combination of convex functions is convex. A maximum of convex functions is convex.

These rules can be used to prove the functions in your question are convex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Sure! By the way, your last edit seems to have deleted the questions.

Comment: Oops..Thanks for heads up! I will put it back